# How to Hide Eclipse editor while doing back ground processing

Tags: eclipse-plugin

How to Hide Eclipse editor while doing back ground processing, means 
How to do some working pro-grammatically on Eclipse editor without showing it to end-user.

I am working on UML diagram. Activity Diagram gets jumbled on editor when making pro-grammatically, Then I call 'Arrange Selection' action to arrange Activity, it works properly. Now I need to save the images of all UML diagrams on the fly but running as a background processing; editor should not be opened to the user but 'Arrange Selection' code requires editor to be opened & diagram elements should be selected e.g.

```
org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.actions.internal.ArrangeAction.createArrangeSelectionAction(IWorkbenchPage workbenchPage)
```

How can I achieve this.

Please tell if this is possible??

Thanks in advance

Kishore

Answer (score 1):

You can run background jobs in the Eclipse IDE.

In Eclipse Help, see the Platform Plug-in Developer Guide > Programmer's Guide > Runtime overview > Concurrency infrastructure for an explanation and examples on how to create Eclipse background jobs.